# Content of text file is getting overwritten by previous content in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to export the registry keys to a text file. But, it is only exporting the output of last registry key. It is overwriting the previous outputs. Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?
Thanks in Advance.

```
Function ExportRegistry ($logName)
{
    $RegExportPlaceHolder = "$env:windir\Temp" + "\$logName"
    if (!(Test-Path $RegExportPlaceHolder))
    {
        New-Item -path $RegExportPlaceHolder -type "file"
    }
    else
    {
        Add-Content $RegExportPlaceHolder $string
    }

    $CBSKey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\RebootPending"
    regedit /e /y $RegExportPlaceHolder $CBSKey

    $WUAUKey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired"
    regedit /e /y $RegExportPlaceHolder $WUAUKey

    $UEVKey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\UpdateExeVolatile"
    regedit /e /y $RegExportPlaceHolder $UEVKey
}

$RegExportLogName = "RegExport.txt"
$ExportReg = ExportRegistry $RegExportLogName
```

In my case I only get the output of `$UEVKey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\UpdateExeVolatile"` and the output of previous keys are getting overwritten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`regedit` doesn't append to the output file. If you want several keys exported to the same file you must export them to individual files first and then concatenate those files. I would also recommend using `reg.exe` instead of `regedit.exe` for the export, because only the former will give you a proper exit code that allows you to determine if something went wrong.

```
$CBSKey = 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\RebootPending'
& reg export $CBSKey "${RegExportPlaceHolder}.1" /y

$WUAUKey = 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired'
& reg export $WUAUKey "${RegExportPlaceHolder}.2" /y

$UEVKey = 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\UpdateExeVolatile'
& reg export $UEVKey "${RegExportPlaceHolder}.3" /y

'Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00' | Set-Content $RegExportPlaceHolder
Get-ChildItem "${RegExportPlaceHolder}.*" | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-Object -Skip 1
} | Add-Content $RegExportPlaceHolder

Remove-Item "${RegExportPlaceHolder}.*" -Force
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. If a registry key is not present then I am getting this error : reg.exe : ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

Comment: Of course you are. That's basically the point of using `reg.exe`: so you can actually see what's going on when something goes wrong. You can suppress the error output by redirecting it like this: `& reg export ... 2>$null`.

Comment: why is the script creating multiple files?

Comment: Yes Understood. How can we exactly suppress the error using & reg export ... 2>$null ? It is giving redirection error.

Comment: Please show the exact command you're running and the exact error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174118/discussion-between-beginner-and-ansgar-wiechers).